# Git Pull Windows Azure Website

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, git-pull

I have created a new Azure Web App *using the portal*, and selecting the [Django template from the Marketplace](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/ptvs/django/).

I now want to do a `git pull` on this source, so I can work on it.

I've found a ton of information on how to `push`, setup CI, integrate BitBucket etc, but nothing on how to pull it.

I *could* just download it via FTP first, but want to know if there is a better/proper way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited: You'll need to ensure you have Local Git Repository chosen as a deployment source. Scroll down on your web app's info blade and click on Deployment to get it setup. 
[image]

After this is configured, you'll find your Git URL under Settings >> Properties. (Note: it also appears in my screenshot below in my "Essentials" quick view, but it's always available in Properties)

Also under Properties you'll find Deployment Credentials where you can change your FTP/Git username and password. This will be different from the Microsoft account associated with your Azure subscription. 
[image]

Once you have the git URL, you can `git clone` the repo to your local machine and do a `git pull` if things change.
[image]

Comment: I don't see any Git options in properties for this web app. Do I need to enable another feature somewhere?

Comment: I found the URL in the older portal under Configure | Deployments.

Comment: I see. I just updated the answer to include the Deployment config option from the Preview portal.

Comment: Aha! I was already linked to BiTbucket for deployments. Removed that and I'm off and running.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment on the accepted answer, but if anybody is unable to find the git URL, Azure seems to sometimes pre-configure for FTP and only work with one source at a time. If you go to 'Deployment options', then Disconnect it'll remove the FTP - then you can click Setup and choose 'Local Git' like the above example.